# Canon LBP 3300 Laser Jet Printer display orange light (load paper), whenever i give command of printing in my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop?

Tags: printing

I am using Canon LBP3300 printer through USB attached to my desktop. I have installed Canon LBP3300 printer driver in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop by following the procedure given in the below site :

[https://github.com/hieplpvip/ubuntu_canon_printer.](https://github.com/hieplpvip/ubuntu_canon_printer)

Though it show that printer installed successfully but whenever i give printing command, my Canon LBP3300 Printer display orange light (load paper), though paper is already there in cassette.